# Unable to change colour of a specified cell of a frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Created some labels as tables.
After Creating labels of tables with data. I need to change specified cell of a label  table cell colour.

```
from tkinter import Tk,Frame,Label

mainwindow=Tk()

mainframe=Frame(mainwindow,bg="white")
mainframe.pack(fill="both",expand=True)


labels=[]
#grid data
for i in range(4):
    grid_frame=Frame(mainframe)
    label=Label(mainframe,text="Player "+str(i+1),bg="black",fg="white",padx=5,pady=5)
    label.config(font=("Arial",18))
    label.pack(fill="x")
    for row in range(3):
        for column in range(5):
            label=Label(grid_frame,text="Item ",bg="green",fg="white",padx=5,pady=5)
            label.grid(row=row,column=column,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nsew")
            grid_frame.grid_columnconfigure(column,weight=1)

    grid_frame.pack(fill="x")
    labels.append(label)

#here I am trying to change 2nd label table 2nd row 3rd column cell color. But it is changing for other label.
labels[1]=Label(grid_frame,text="Item ",bg="orange",fg="white",padx=5,pady=5)
labels[1].grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nsew")


mainwindow.mainloop()
```

Kindly please help

Comment: `labels[1].config(bg='orange', fg='white')` also remove `labels[1].grid(row=1,column=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nsew")`

Comment: Also he has to change where he appends the labels into the `labels` list. Otherwise he would not store all the labels. Look at my answer I have changed it there so it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change 2 things in your code:

1. You have to add the labels inside the `for` loop.
2. Change the color of the label by using `.config()` method. And change the `"bg"` and `"fg"` attributes as you want.

And this is the code that will work:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Frame,Label

mainwindow=Tk()

mainframe=Frame(mainwindow,bg="white")
mainframe.pack(fill="both",expand=True)


labels=[]
#grid data
for i in range(4):
    grid_frame=Frame(mainframe)
    label=Label(mainframe,text="Player "+str(i+1),bg="black",fg="white",padx=5,pady=5)
    label.config(font=("Arial",18))
    label.pack(fill="x")

    for row in range(3):
        for column in range(5):
            label=Label(grid_frame,text="Item ",bg="green",fg="white",padx=5,pady=5)
            label.grid(row=row,column=column,padx=5,pady=5,sticky="nsew")

            grid_frame.grid_columnconfigure(column,weight=1)
            
            #Add all labels here:
            labels.append(label)

    grid_frame.pack(fill="x")

#Change colors of the 1st label
labels[0].config(bg = "orange", fg = "white")

#Change colors of the last label
labels[-1].config(bg = "orange", fg = "white")

mainwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the answer helped you please leave a thumbs up! :)

Comment: why `labels[1*1*1-1]` instead of  `labels[0]`?

Comment: Just to showcase that he can index the list like x, y, z coordinates.

Comment: Check for this `labels[4*2*3 - 1]` and tell me which label will change color.

Comment: Ah okay I see your point! Answer has been edited and now it is accurate I think.